# How to create unit tests in Python for 2 methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I need suggestions how to write unit tests for the code below. First method accepts an integer between 1 and 50 and returns a string. If the integer is a multiple of 3 it returns string "Hello". If the integer is a multiple of 5 it returns string "World". And if the integer is a multiple of both 3 and 5 it returns string "HelloWorld".
Second method accepts a string and returns the same string reversed. For example string "Hello" the method will return "olleH". Hopefully the methods are now ok. My class is called MyMethods.

But the part i need help with is to create another python code file. A unit test file which imports the class MyMethods and tests both functions in a few cases.

I would be glad if anyone could help me with this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import math

class MyMethods:

    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def ConvertToHelloWorldString(self, toConvert):

        if toConvert < 1 or toConvert > 50:
            raise ValueError ("numberToConvert was outside of the valid range")

        
        if toConvert % 3 == 0 and toConvert % 5 == 0:
            return "HelloWorld" 
        elif toConvert % 3 == 0:
            return "Hello"
        elif toConvert % 5 == 0:
            return "World" 
        else:
            return str(toConvert)

    def ReverseString(self, toReverse):
        if toReverse is None or toReverse == "":
            raise ValueError("The string to reverse must contain characters")

        return toReverse[::-1]
```

Comment: Hint: turn to your favorite search engine and enter "python unit tests". There is really a lot of information out their to research ...

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @GhostCat's sentiment and highly recommend you do your own research, I spent considerable time researching the same topic and I ultimately established the following template for my python projects:

### The Directory Structure

Given I want to create a new python project, I set up the file structure as follows:

```
ProjectDirectory\
    Data\
    Src\
        __init__.py
        myclass.py
    Tests\
        __init__.py
        test_myclass.py
    __init__.py
```

### Unit Test File Structure

Within the **test_myclass.py** file, the file template follows the following basic structure

```
import unittest
import pytest

from src.myclass import Myclass

class test_Myclass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_existance(self):
        print('\tTest Existence')
        self.assertTrue(True)
        
    def test_fulldata_initialization(self):  
        print('\tTest full data initialization')
        tc = Myclass()
        
    def test_method1(self):
        print('\tTest Method 1 ')
        
    .
    
    .
    
    .
    
    .


def Myclass_tests():
    print ('******     Testing Myclass Functionality  ********')
    testclass = test_Myclass()
    testclass.test_existance()  #Verifies the testt is running
    testclass.test_fulldata_initialization()
    testclass.test_method1()
    .
    .
    .
    .
    
    print('\n*******     Myclass Tests Complete   ********\n') 
    
    
    
def main():
    Myclass_tests()
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```